# Failed to Upgrade from macOs High Sierra GM to Public Release

Tags: install, high-sierra

I have a MPB with macOS 10.13 Beta (17A362a) (GM), when trying to install the public release from the App Store I get the following error:

> An error occurred while preparing the installation. Try running the application again.

Any idea what is wrong with the installation?

These are the relevant entries I've found in the logs:

```
    Sep 26 00:06:18 Gils-MacBook-Pro InstallAssistant[873]: objc[873]: Class OSISSystemInfo is implemented in both /Applications/Install macOS High Sierra.app/Contents/MacOS/InstallAssistant (0x109da1ec8) and /Applications/Install macOS High Sierra.app/Contents/Frameworks/OSInstallerSetup.framework/Versions/A/OSInstallerSetup (0x10d24fa70). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Sep 26 00:06:18 Gils-MacBook-Pro InstallAssistant[873]: objc[873]: Class OSISSystemInfo is implemented in both /Applications/Install macOS High Sierra.app/Contents/MacOS/InstallAssistant (0x109da1ec8) and /Applications/Install macOS High Sierra.app/Contents/PlugIns/DiskManagement.IABundle/Contents/MacOS/DiskManagement (0x1143e2990). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Sep 26 00:06:18 Gils-MacBook-Pro osinstallersetupd[875]: objc[875]: Class APFSMachineSupport is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OSInstaller.framework/Versions/A/OSInstaller (0x7fffb59e7270) and /Applications/Install macOS High Sierra.app/Contents/Frameworks/OSInstallerSetup.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/OSInstallerSetupInternal.framework/Versions/A/OSInstallerSetupInternal (0x10f51a570). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Sep 26 00:06:53 Gils-MacBook-Pro Installer Progress[965]: Progress UI App Starting
Sep 26 00:06:53 Gils-MacBook-Pro Installer Progress[965]: No boot windows available
Sep 26 00:06:53 Gils-MacBook-Pro Installer Progress[965]: Hiding the cursor in Progress UI
Sep 26 00:06:53 Gils-MacBook-Pro Installer Progress[965]: caller = /Applications/Install macOS High Sierra.app/Contents/Frameworks/OSInstallerSetup.framework/Versions/A/Resources/osishelperd
Sep 26 00:06:53 Gils-MacBook-Pro Installer Progress[965]: Version 2
Sep 26 00:06:53 Gils-MacBook-Pro Installer Progress[965]: Clearing phase info
Sep 26 00:06:53 Gils-MacBook-Pro osishelperd[905]: Add phase named "OS Installer", progress 5.000000, delayInSeconds 0
Sep 26 00:06:53 Gils-MacBook-Pro Installer Progress[965]: IASGetCurrentInstallPhaseList: Unable to get phases
Sep 26 00:06:53 Gils-MacBook-Pro Installer Progress[965]: IASGetCurrentInstallPhase: Unable to get the current phase name
Sep 26 00:06:53 Gils-MacBook-Pro Installer Progress[965]: phaseName = (null)
Sep 26 00:06:53 Gils-MacBook-Pro Installer Progress[965]: Current phase name wasn't saved, using the first phase in the list, current phase = "(null)"
Sep 26 00:06:53 Gils-MacBook-Pro Installer Progress[965]: _currentPhase = "(null)", _phases = (null)
Sep 26 00:06:53 Gils-MacBook-Pro osishelperd[905]: Add phase named "OS Installer 2", progress 55.000000, delayInSeconds 0
Sep 26 00:06:53 Gils-MacBook-Pro Installer Progress[965]: IASClearInstallProgress: Clearing Registry
Sep 26 00:06:53 Gils-MacBook-Pro Installer Progress[965]: totalPercentage = 0.000000
Sep 26 00:06:53 Gils-MacBook-Pro Installer Progress[965]: phases = (
Sep 26 00:06:53 Gils-MacBook-Pro Installer Progress[965]: IASSetCurrentInstallPhaseList: phases set to (
            InstallPhase = "Boot 1";
            InstallPhasePercentageKey = 5;
Sep 26 00:06:53 Gils-MacBook-Pro Installer Progress[965]: IASSetCurrentInstallPhase: Current phase name set to "Boot 1"
Sep 26 00:06:53 Gils-MacBook-Pro Installer Progress[965]: totalPercentage = 5.000000
Sep 26 00:06:53 Gils-MacBook-Pro Installer Progress[965]: phases = (
Sep 26 00:06:53 Gils-MacBook-Pro Installer Progress[965]: IASSetCurrentInstallPhaseList: phases set to (
            InstallPhase = "Boot 1";
            InstallPhasePercentageKey = 5;
            InstallPhase = "Language Chooser";
            InstallPhasePercentageKey = 5;
Sep 26 00:06:53 Gils-MacBook-Pro Installer Progress[965]: IASSetCurrentInstallPhase: Current phase name set to "Boot 1"
Sep 26 00:06:53 Gils-MacBook-Pro Installer Progress[965]: totalPercentage = 10.000000
Sep 26 00:06:53 Gils-MacBook-Pro Installer Progress[965]: phases = (
        ""
Sep 26 00:06:53 Gils-MacBook-Pro Installer Progress[965]: IASSetCurrentInstallPhaseList: phases set to (
            InstallPhase = "Boot 1";
            InstallPhasePercentageKey = 5;
            InstallPhase = "Language Chooser";
            InstallPhasePercentageKey = 5;
            InstallPhase = "OS Installer";
            InstallPhasePercentageKey = 5;
Sep 26 00:06:53 Gils-MacBook-Pro Installer Progress[965]: IASSetCurrentInstallPhase: Current phase name set to "Boot 1"
Sep 26 00:06:53 Gils-MacBook-Pro Installer Progress[965]: totalPercentage = 15.000000
Sep 26 00:06:53 Gils-MacBook-Pro Installer Progress[965]: phases = (
        "",
Sep 26 00:06:53 Gils-MacBook-Pro Installer Progress[965]: IASSetCurrentInstallPhaseList: phases set to (
            InstallPhase = "Boot 1";
            InstallPhasePercentageKey = 5;
            InstallPhase = "Language Chooser";
            InstallPhasePercentageKey = 5;
            InstallPhase = "OS Installer";
            InstallPhasePercentageKey = 5;
            InstallPhase = "EFI Firmware Update";
            InstallPhasePercentageKey = 5;
Sep 26 00:06:53 Gils-MacBook-Pro Installer Progress[965]: IASSetCurrentInstallPhase: Current phase name set to "Boot 1"
Sep 26 00:06:53 Gils-MacBook-Pro Installer Progress[965]: totalPercentage = 20.000000
Sep 26 00:06:53 Gils-MacBook-Pro Installer Progress[965]: phases = (
        "",
Sep 26 00:06:53 Gils-MacBook-Pro Installer Progress[965]: IASSetCurrentInstallPhaseList: phases set to (
            InstallPhase = "Boot 1";
            InstallPhasePercentageKey = 5;
            InstallPhase = "Language Chooser";
            InstallPhasePercentageKey = 5;
            InstallPhase = "OS Installer";
            InstallPhasePercentageKey = 5;
            InstallPhase = "EFI Firmware Update";
            InstallPhasePercentageKey = 5;
            InstallPhase = "Boot 2";
            InstallPhasePercentageKey = 5;
Sep 26 00:06:53 Gils-MacBook-Pro Installer Progress[965]: IASSetCurrentInstallPhase: Current phase name set to "Boot 1"
Sep 26 00:06:53 Gils-MacBook-Pro Installer Progress[965]: totalPercentage = 25.000000
Sep 26 00:06:53 Gils-MacBook-Pro Installer Progress[965]: phases = (
        "",
Sep 26 00:06:53 Gils-MacBook-Pro Installer Progress[965]: IASSetCurrentInstallPhaseList: phases set to (
            InstallPhase = "Boot 1";
            InstallPhasePercentageKey = 5;
            InstallPhase = "Language Chooser";
            InstallPhasePercentageKey = 5;
            InstallPhase = "OS Installer";
            InstallPhasePercentageKey = 5;
            InstallPhase = "EFI Firmware Update";
            InstallPhasePercentageKey = 5;
            InstallPhase = "Boot 2";
            InstallPhasePercentageKey = 5;
            InstallPhase = "Language Chooser 2";
            InstallPhasePercentageKey = 5;
Sep 26 00:06:53 Gils-MacBook-Pro Installer Progress[965]: IASSetCurrentInstallPhase: Current phase name set to "Boot 1"
Sep 26 00:06:53 Gils-MacBook-Pro Installer Progress[965]: totalPercentage = 30.000000
Sep 26 00:06:53 Gils-MacBook-Pro Installer Progress[965]: phases = (
        "",
        ""
Sep 26 00:06:53 Gils-MacBook-Pro Installer Progress[965]: IASSetCurrentInstallPhaseList: phases set to (
            InstallPhase = "Boot 1";
            InstallPhasePercentageKey = 5;
            InstallPhase = "Language Chooser";
            InstallPhasePercentageKey = 5;
            InstallPhase = "OS Installer";
            InstallPhasePercentageKey = 5;
            InstallPhase = "EFI Firmware Update";
            InstallPhasePercentageKey = 5;
            InstallPhase = "Boot 2";
            InstallPhasePercentageKey = 5;
            InstallPhase = "Language Chooser 2";
            InstallPhasePercentageKey = 5;
            InstallPhase = "OS Installer 2";
            InstallPhasePercentageKey = 55;
Sep 26 00:06:53 Gils-MacBook-Pro Installer Progress[965]: IASSetCurrentInstallPhase: Current phase name set to "Boot 1"
Sep 26 00:06:53 Gils-MacBook-Pro Installer Progress[965]: totalPercentage = 85.000000
Sep 26 00:06:53 Gils-MacBook-Pro Installer Progress[965]: phases = (
        "",
        "",
Sep 26 00:06:53 Gils-MacBook-Pro Installer Progress[965]: IASSetCurrentInstallPhaseList: phases set to (
            InstallPhase = "Boot 1";
            InstallPhasePercentageKey = 5;
            InstallPhase = "Language Chooser";
            InstallPhasePercentageKey = 5;
            InstallPhase = "OS Installer";
            InstallPhasePercentageKey = 5;
            InstallPhase = "EFI Firmware Update";
            InstallPhasePercentageKey = 5;
            InstallPhase = "Boot 2";
            InstallPhasePercentageKey = 5;
            InstallPhase = "Language Chooser 2";
            InstallPhasePercentageKey = 5;
            InstallPhase = "OS Installer 2";
            InstallPhasePercentageKey = 55;
            InstallPhase = "Boot 3";
            InstallPhasePercentageKey = 5;
Sep 26 00:06:53 Gils-MacBook-Pro Installer Progress[965]: IASSetCurrentInstallPhase: Current phase name set to "Boot 1"
Sep 26 00:06:53 Gils-MacBook-Pro Installer Progress[965]: totalPercentage = 90.000000
Sep 26 00:06:53 Gils-MacBook-Pro Installer Progress[965]: phases = (
        "",
        "",
Sep 26 00:06:53 Gils-MacBook-Pro Installer Progress[965]: IASSetCurrentInstallPhaseList: phases set to (
            InstallPhase = "Boot 1";
            InstallPhasePercentageKey = 5;
            InstallPhase = "Language Chooser";
            InstallPhasePercentageKey = 5;
            InstallPhase = "OS Installer";
            InstallPhasePercentageKey = 5;
            InstallPhase = "EFI Firmware Update";
            InstallPhasePercentageKey = 5;
            InstallPhase = "Boot 2";
            InstallPhasePercentageKey = 5;
            InstallPhase = "Language Chooser 2";
            InstallPhasePercentageKey = 5;
            InstallPhase = "OS Installer 2";
            InstallPhasePercentageKey = 55;
            InstallPhase = "Boot 3";
            InstallPhasePercentageKey = 5;
            InstallPhase = "Setup Assistant";
            InstallPhasePercentageKey = 10;
Sep 26 00:06:53 Gils-MacBook-Pro Installer Progress[965]: IASSetCurrentInstallPhase: Current phase name set to "Boot 1"
Sep 26 00:06:53 Gils-MacBook-Pro Installer Progress[965]: Progress app is loading…
Sep 26 00:06:53 Gils-MacBook-Pro Installer Progress[965]: Progress app is running…
Sep 26 00:06:59 Gils-MacBook-Pro osinstallersetupd[875]: BUG in libdispatch client: dispatch_mig_server: mach_msg() failed (ipc/send) invalid data - 0x10000002
```

Comment: Is upgrading using the app store download the preferred way? I assumed there would be a patch available in a day or two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve this by deleting the installation file and downloading it again.

Comment: I get stuck in loop rebooting and 20 min later getting an error again. How do I break out of the loop and get to a usable state where I can delete and re-download?

Comment: I booted in safe mode, reseted the SMC and the mac booted fine, after the update failed.

Comment: Not sure why I had so many problems with the Command-R keyboard shortcut to get to recovery mode. But I eventually needed to erase my HD and start over. Wish I had a backup for all my apps, but otherwise not a big deal thanks to cloud.